# cURL error 8: Invalid Content-Length: value

Tags: php, curl, wampserver, guzzle, php-curl

When I try to send a request with Guzzle library, I get this error.

> GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException
>   cURL error 8: Invalid Content-Length: value (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

I've seen the above link, but it doesn't have any helpful information.

I use wamp64 and windows for development.

and the following is my code:

```
use guzzle\http\Client;

$headers = [
    'User-agent'=> 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'Accept'=> 
 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding'=> 'gzip',
];

$client = new Client();
$start_time = time();
$response = $client->request(
    'get',
    'https://www.google.com',
    ['headers' => $headers]
);
```

**EDIT:**
It works properly for `https://yahoo.com` but for `http://yahoo.com` it raises previous error.

Answer (score 3):

i suspect your connection is behind a MITM-style intercepting proxy that sends wrong Content-Length headers, but in any case, you can tell curl to ignore Content-Length with the `CURLOPT_IGNORE_CONTENT_LENGTH` option - unfortunately PHP lacks the constant for CURLOPT_IGNORE_CONTENT_LENGTH , but it's magic number is 136, meaning you can just do

```
if(!defined("CURLOPT_IGNORE_CONTENT_LENGTH")){
    define("CURLOPT_IGNORE_CONTENT_LENGTH",136);
}
$response = $client->request(
    'get',
    'https://www.google.com',
    ['headers' => $headers, 'curl'=>[CURLOPT_IGNORE_CONTENT_LENGTH=>true]]
);
```

(note that this may come with a significant performance penalty, as now curl have to keep reading from the socket until the server closes it, instead of reading until Content-Length bytes have been received, depending on the server configuration, that could be A LOT slower, many servers keep connections open for a socket-reuse scheme. you probably want to add the http header `Connection: close` while you have to ignore content-length headers.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with cURL and sorted it out with

`'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))`

where

`$data_string` contains all the `POST` data

in your case it would look like this

```
use guzzle\http\Client;

$headers = [
    'User-agent'=> 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'Content-Length' => '0',
    'Accept'=> 
 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding'=> 'gzip',
];

$client = new Client();
$start_time = time();
$response = $client->request(
    'get',
    'https://www.google.com',
    ['headers' => $headers]
);
```